# Excel: How To Select A Cell Using Multiple Criteria What's Wrong With My Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to select a value from the `Rate` column based on the `Low` and `High` columns.

If the value is in the range it returns the Rate for that row.
This should return `22%.

But I keep getting a `#VALUE!`  error.

The formula is: `=FILTER(A1:A8, B1:B8<=B17*C1:C8>=B17)`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include parenthesis to separate the conditions. Your formula will be:

```
=FILTER(A1:A8, (B1:B8<=B17)*(C1:C8>=B17))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!   this worked!